# How to get a value which is a List from a JSONObject in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, org.json

I have a following JSON:

```
{"data":["str1", "str2", "str3"]}
```

I want to get a `List`, i.e. `["str1", "str2", "str3"]`

My code is:

```java
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
List list = new ArrayList();
...
// adding data in json
...
list = (List) json.get("data");
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize a little bit of code like it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String data = "{\"data\":[\"str1\", \"str2\", \"str3\"]}";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(
                data);
         
        JSONArray jasonArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
        List list = new ArrayList();

        int size = jasonArray.length();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < size) {
            list.add(jasonArray.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(list);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get this data as a JsonArray

Comment: I don't quite uderstand the syntax. I have this error: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.util.List if I use list = (List) json .getJSONArray("data");

Comment: insted of JSONArray use JsonArray.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to parse a JSON string using Java code. It is recommended to use a JSON library for Java. There are several. The below code uses [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). There are many online examples such as [Convert String to JsonObject with Gson](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-string-to-jsonobject). You should also familiarize yourself with the Gson [API](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/module-summary.html).

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"data\":[\"str1\", \"str2\", \"str3\"]}";
        JsonElement elem = JsonParser.parseString(json);
        if (elem.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject obj = elem.getAsJsonObject();
            elem = obj.get("data");
            if (elem.isJsonArray()) {
                JsonArray arr = elem.getAsJsonArray();
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                int count = arr.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    elem = arr.get(i);
                    if (elem.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                        String str = elem.getAsString();
                        list.add(str);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(list);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code gives the following output:

```
[str1, str2, str3]
```

There are other ways to convert the `JsonArray` to a `List`. The above is not the only way. As I wrote earlier, peruse the API documentation and search the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, the `JSONArray` object stores the json data in an `ArrayList<Object>`, and it has a method called `toList()`.  There's absolutely no need to loop through the `JSONArray` in order to set values in the array.  The simpler code would look something like this

```java
String data = "{\"data\":[\"str1\", \"str2\", \"str3\"]}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);

List<Object> list = json.getJSONArray("data").toList();

System.out.println(myList);
```

*Note:  This will create a list of generic Objects.  The currently accepted answer doesn't define a type for the List, which is unsafe.  It doesn't enforce type safety, and errors will occur at runtime instead of at compile time.*

If you want to convert all of the inner objects to a String, you can do this by upcasting the List to an Object, and then casting it to a `List<String>`.  I don't particularly recommend it, but it can be done like this.  `List<String> list = (List<String>) (Object) json.getJSONArray("data").toList();`.

A better way of casting the value to a specific type would be via a stream to call the `Object.toString()` method.

```java
List<String> list = json.getJSONArray("data").toList().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or, if you have a specific type you want to cast it to, you can use

```java
List<MyObject> list = json.getJSONArray("data").toList().stream().map(jsonObject -> (MyObject) jsonObject).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Finally, as others have pointed out, there are better libraries for dealing with json.  [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is a great library, however I personally prefer [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).  They both offer similar resources, but I've found that Jackson's `ObjectMapper` is more customizable and more widely used.